# How to use R environments inside package?

Tags: r

I'm having a problem where a variable seems to not be found using `with()`

I have a package, with internal data that is an environment (ENV); so every function within my package can access (and modify) ENV.

Essentially I'm using the following code inside my package:

In `/data-raw` I make an environment, and save it to `/data`

```
ENV = new.env()
ENV$A = 2
ENV$B = 3
```

And in my package:

```
foo<-function(bar){
  with(ENV,{
    if(nrow(bar)==0){
      print(ENV$A)
    } else {
      print(ENV$B)
    }
  })
}

bar = data.frame()
foo(bar)
```

What I actually get is: `Error in nrow(bar) { : object '.result' not found`

I thought the function environment would be the parent of the `with` environment... Can I not access the function's variables like this?

Thanks for any help.

### Update

So, they're definitely in different places. The parent environment inside the function is my package namespace, whereas the parent inside `with` is the global environment.

Comment: You have the same issue with `with` outside packages, of course. What matters is whether `bar` can be found from `ENV`’s parent environment or not.

Comment: Another thing: `R CMD Check` will presumably complain about this use of `with` inside a package since it can’t verify that the names in the environment exist. You’ll get an ugly warning about undeclared global identifiers. Really, the best solution is not to use `with` and its ilk inside package code.

Comment: Thanks, this has been really helpful. I'll replace `with` with ENV$A instead. I was only using `with` because it seemed to make clearer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the function environment would be the parent of the `with` environment...

No: the parent environment of `with` is the parent environment *of the environment*. In fact, that’s one of the fundamental issues that commands such `with` have.

To work around this you could convert your environment to a list (via `as.list`). Of course that *copies* all objects in the environment so it’s potentially inefficient. It also makes modifying objects inside the environment impossible.